# SQL Cut Stretch Date into various stretchs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a large stretch of dates in one table and some dates to cut in other table.

With this I need to get another table with all the stretchs inside the large one cut by the others dates.

[image]

I have this for the moment:

```
DECLARE @UTCSTARTDATE DATETIME='2020-01-20 00:00:00.00'
DECLARE @UTCENDDATE DATETIME='2020-01-20 04:00:00.00'

DECLARE @T1 TABLE
(
    StartTime DATETIME,
    EndTime DATETIME,
    table_id int
)

DECLARE @T2 TABLE
(
    CutTime DATETIME,
    table2_id int
)


INSERT INTO @T1 SELECT @UTCSTARTDATE,@UTCENDDATE,1

INSERT INTO @T2 SELECT myCut,myID FROM (VALUES('2020-01-20 01:00:00.00',1),('2020-01-20 02:30:00.00',1),('2020-01-20 03:00:00.00',2))t2(myCut,myID)


SELECT * FROM @T1

SELECT * FROM @T2 order by CutTime ASC



DECLARE @STRETCHHOURSTABLE TABLE
    (
        startDate               DATETIME,
        endDate                 DATETIME

    );

    ;WITH DATESPLITTER AS
    (
            SELECT 
                StartTime AS stretchStartDate, 
                (SELECT TOP(1) CutTime FROM @T2 where CutTime < EndTime AND table_id = table2_id order by CutTime ASC) AS stretchEndDate,
                EndTime AS RealEndTime,
                table_id AS RealID
            FROM @T1
        UNION ALL 
            SELECT 
                stretchEndDate,
                (SELECT TOP(1) CutTime FROM @T2 where CutTime > stretchEndDate AND CutTime < RealEndTime AND table2_id = RealID order by CutTime ASC) AS stretchEndDate,
                RealEndTime,
                RealID
            FROM DATESPLITTER
            WHERE stretchEndDate < @UTCENDDATE
    )
        INSERT INTO @STRETCHHOURSTABLE (startDate, endDate)
        SELECT 
            stretchStartDate,
            CASE    
                WHEN @UTCENDDATE < stretchEndDate THEN @UTCENDDATE
                ELSE stretchEndDate
            END 
        FROM DATESPLITTER

SELECT * FROM @STRETCHHOURSTABLE
```

Comment: So what is your question here exactly? You don't ask us anything.  What are you expected results for the data supplied? Why isn't what you have working?

Comment: my question is that what i wrote there doesnt work, i need something that do the same thing on the img

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't a qusetion, that's a statement. *"What are you expected results for the data supplied? **Why isn't what you have working?**"* We can't answer your question, when you don't ask one.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to basically be `lead()` after `union all`:

```
select dt, lead(dt) over (order by dt)
from ((select v.dt
       from @t1 t1 cross apply
            (values (t1.startTime), (t1.endTime)) v(dt)
      ) union all
      (select t2.cuttime
       from @t2 t2
      )
     ) t
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=80c3833f1fe8356efe8d3fa784662bf8) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, I have made changes:

```
DECLARE @UTCSTARTDATE DATETIME='2020-01-20 00:00:00.00'
DECLARE @UTCENDDATE DATETIME='2020-01-20 04:00:00.00'

DECLARE @T1 TABLE( StartTime DATETIME, EndTime DATETIME, table_id int);
DECLARE @T2 TABLE ( CutTime DATETIME, table2_id int);


INSERT INTO @T1 SELECT @UTCSTARTDATE,@UTCENDDATE,1
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES('2020-01-20 01:00:00.00',1),('2020-01-20 02:30:00.00',1),('2020-01-20 03:00:00.00',2);

SELECT * FROM @T1
SELECT * FROM @T2 order by CutTime ASC;

DECLARE @STRETCHHOURSTABLE TABLE (startDate DATETIME, endDate DATETIME);

WITH DATESPLITTER AS
    (
            SELECT 
                StartTime AS stretchStartDate,
                (select cuttime from (SELECT row_number() over(partition by table2_id order by CutTime ASC) rn, CutTime FROM @T2 where CutTime < EndTime AND table_id = table2_id)a
                  where a.rn = 1) AS stretchEndDate,
                EndTime AS RealEndTime,
                table_id AS RealID
            FROM @T1
        UNION ALL 
            SELECT 
                stretchEndDate,
                ISNULL((select cuttime from (SELECT row_number() over(partition by table2_id order by CutTime ASC) rn, CutTime FROM @T2 where CutTime > stretchEndDate AND CutTime < RealEndTime AND table2_id = RealID)a
                  where a.rn = 1), RealEndTime) AS stretchEndDate,
                RealEndTime,
                RealID
            FROM DATESPLITTER
            WHERE stretchEndDate < @UTCENDDATE
    )

INSERT INTO @STRETCHHOURSTABLE (startDate, endDate)
SELECT  stretchStartDate,
        CASE
            WHEN @UTCENDDATE < stretchEndDate THEN @UTCENDDATE
                ELSE stretchEndDate
                    END as sommm
FROM DATESPLITTER

SELECT * FROM @STRETCHHOURSTABLE
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what you changed/fixed to make it clear what was changed and why.

Comment: Used row_number() instead of TOP in cte, and used ISNULL for strechenddate to avoid null in enddate col.